# Custom tags with Doxygen

Tags: doxygen

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to create a custom tag using Doxygen. I did find the ALIAS configuration file option but that does not do exactly what I need. Basically in my code I want to be able to write something like

```
/// \req Requirement #322 - blah blah
```

And then have Doxygen create a list like it does for `\bug` and `\todo` commands for lines that have this custom tag. Is this possible with Doxygen?

Comment: This does not seem to work with XML (C#) documenting style.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The generalization of `\bug` and `\todo` is `\xrefitem`.

The solution I suggest is:

- in Doxyfile:

  ```
  ALIASES += "req=\xrefitem req \"Requirement\" \"Requirements\" "
  ```
- in documented code:

  ```
  /// \req #42 - The system shall work in any situation
  ```

Comment: Excellent, I did not see that while looking at the manual.

Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 29):

Thanks mouviciel! I have adopted your solution and extended it for my purposes.

The text below goes into my Doxyfile:

```
ALIASES += req{1}="\ref SRTX_\1 \"SRTX-\1\" "
ALIASES += satisfy{1}="\xrefitem satisfy \"Satisfies requirement\" \"Requirement Implementation\" \1"
ALIASES += verify{1}="\xrefitem verify \"Verifies requirement\" \"Requirement Verification\" \1"
```

Where SRTX is the name of my project and is used as a prefix to requirements.

Then I create a file called Requirements.dox that provides a link between the requirement id and a URL for the requirement in my requirements management tool (an issue tracker in my case).

```
/**
@page Requirements

@section Build1

@anchor SRTX_1113
<a href="https://foo.bar.com/mantis/view.php?id=1113">SRTX-1113</a>

@anchor SRTX_1114
<a href="https://foo.bar.com/mantis/view.php?id=1114">SRTX-1114</a>

*/
```

One could also put the text of the requirement in the anchor tag if you didn't need to link to an external source.

In my code I have:

```
/**
 * This is the basic executive that schedules processes.
 * @satisfy{@req{1114}}
 */
class Scheduler: public Process
{
    ...
}
```

And in my tests I put:

```
/**
 * Provide a number of tests for process scheduling.
 * @verify{@req{1114}}
 */
class Scheduler_ut : public CppUnit::TestFixture
{
    ...
}
```

This gives me related pages for Requirements, Requirements Implementation, and Requirements Verification. It also provides Satisfies requirement and Verifies requirements sections in the class description (or function -- wherever you put the tag).

Comment: Add the `Requirements.dox` specified above in the `INPUT=` variable to be able to see the links, in the "Requirement Implementation" and "Requirement Verification" pages.

Comment: is it also possible to add a reverse lookup, in order to see the list of req and which function implements/versify it ?

Answer (score 7):

***Combining the two answers above***, you can have a single clean requirement tag that will build a cross-reference table, and, also provide a direct link to the requirement repo in your docs:

**Doxygen CONFIG file:**

ALIASES                = `"requirement{1}=@xrefitem requirement \"Requirements\" \"Requirements Traceability\" <a href=\"http://your.requirementtool.com/browse/\1\">\1</a>"`

**Source code:**

`@requirement{REQ-123}` *Brief textual summary of this requirement item*

*This will render in the documentation as:*

**Requirements:**

- [REQ-123](http://your.requirementtool.com/browse/REQ-123) Brief textual summary of this requirement item

Comment: Nice answer - off topic, what open source requirement traceability tool do you recommend to be used in this situation?

Comment: A little off topic? ;)  I've used a _lot_ of commercial requirements tools. Requirements for JIRA (R4J)  provides the best integration (to s/w teams using JIRA) and lightweight usability for small - medium s/ware projects, imho.  I've not evaluated open-source alternatives seriously.  ReqIF was an industry-standard requirements interchange format - take a look at the tools that support that.  Most requirements tools suffer the same problem: they are an _information island_ - with poor integration to your existing tools and processes - try to find something that works with your toolchains.

Comment: Hi @Jay, in this way I get the relationship between the functions that satisfy a requirement and a requirement, obtaining a section in which there are listed all the functions and for each of them the requirements they satisfy.
Is there a way to get the inverse matrix of the relationship?
Obtaining another section in which all the requirements are listed indicating the functions that satisfy each requirement.