# Doxygen \xrefitem doesn't seem to work

Tags: doxygen, command

I'm trying to use xrefitem to create a "Related Page", but it doesn't seem to be working, nor inline. Here is an example:

```
/// \xrefitem makeup "Makeup" "This is made up" ok so it is
/// \xrefitem makeup2 "Makeup2" "This is made up2"  Ok it #ismade"up"
```

I'm using Doxygen 1.5.9. Neither of these show up in the related pages.
I'm also including the comment in a CPP file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two quick thoughts:

First, does this work for you?  (Splitting it up so the text is on a second line...)

```
/// \xrefitem makeup "Makeup" "This is made up" 
/// ok so it is
```

Also, your second example has a number in the tag - is that arbirtrary?  I actually had problems with \addtogroup when someone created a tag named "3D" and it wasn't until hours of hair-pulling that I found that numbers in a tag cause it to be ignored.  Just a thought...

Comment: That was supposed to be two lines, split it at the /// comment.

Answer (score 0):

May be my answer to the question [Custom tags with Doxygen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/537043/custom-tags-with-doxygen) will help you.

There, I propose an example of combined usage of `\xrefitem` and `ALIASES`.

Comment: Thanks. I did initially try that, and after struggling with it a while, it seems like something funny happens with the parser if I place the comment before I enter class documentation (like up with my #include "header.h". I don't even see \todo comments appear =(