# Create new custom command that will add to a section in Doxygen

Tags: doxygen

I would like to create a custom command in Doxygen similar to `\fn` `\param` or `\var`.

For example I would like to be able to create a `\option` command which I would use as follows:

```
/**
  \option option_1 This is the first option.
  \option option_2 This is the second option.
*/
```

With an output like:

**Options:**
          option_1 This is the first option.
          option_2 This is the second option.

A simple substitution alias does not work.  For example with this alias:

```
ALIASES = option="\par Options:\n"
```

I get the following output:

**Options:**
          option_1 This is the first option.

**Options:**
          option_2 This is the second option.

Which is not what I am looking for.

---

**BOUNTY:**

If any further clarification is needed, see my question: [Doxygen - Create custom command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984927/doxygen-create-custom-command)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it is not as clean as @param, you can emulate similar behavior with the following aliases:

```
ALIASES += options="<dl class="params"><dt>Options</dt><dd><table class="params">"
ALIASES += option{2}="<tr><td class="paramname">\1</td><td>\2</td></tr>"
ALIASES += endoptions="</table></dd></dl>"
```

The aliases can be used as follows to produce the output you're looking for:

```
/**
 * @options
 * @option{ option_1, This is the first option. }
 * @option{ option_2, This is the second option. }
 * @endoptions
 */
```

Note: This is HTML-centric and likely will not produce reasonable output for other formats.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like xrefitem might do what you want as answered in this previous question:
[Custom tags with Doxygen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/537043/custom-tags-with-doxygen/537296#537296)

Comment: What that command does is to create a separate page for the given command and create links to that page.  The output for the method documentation is about the same as in my simple alias.  Definitely not what I am looking for.