# Doxygen - Create custom command

Tags: command, arguments, doxygen, param

I think my question is basically the same as this one, but it didn't get a good answer: [Create new custom command that will add to a section in Doxygen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227411/create-new-custom-command-that-will-add-to-a-section-in-doxygen)

I pretty much want to do the same thing, I think. I want to completely duplicate the exact functionality of the `@param` option, except to give it the heading "Options" instead of "Parameters". I want the arguments to be the same (data type, variable name, and description) and want them to look all the same and everything. Literally, the only thing I need different is the heading.

I also tried doing this:

```
ALIASES = option"\par Options:\n"
```

in my Doxyfile, but I also get each individual option in its own section instead of all of them being in the same section. They also don't have the same arguments as the `@param` option.

I also tried to do something with `\xrefitem` which, of course, didn't work. I tried this:

```
ALIASES = option="\xrefitem param \"Option\" \"Options\" "
```

but it looks like `\xrefitem` is used for creating something more like a compiled list from different sections, like the Todo list.

Help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

---

**EDIT:**

Just to clarify, the output I'm looking for would look something like this:

**Options:**
    *string*    **$option1**  This is option 1.
    *string*    **$option2**  This is option 2.

Comment: I'm looking to do the same thing, except have the text "Errors". Perhaps a more complete title to the question might attract more answers. Did you ever submit the feature request? If so it hasn't been acted on 6 years.

Comment: @msc: Sorry, I don't remember if I opened a feature request. Feel free to edit the question if you want, but I'm not looking for an answer to the question anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest I was able to come up with was to use this:

```
@par Options:
@li @e string @b $option1 This is option 1.
@li @e string @b $option2 This is option 2.
```

This almost works decently, except that it doesn't line up each part nicely, like it does with `@param`. So if the first option's name is something like `$option1` and the second option's name is `$thisIsTheSecondOption`, the beginning of the descriptions will not be lined up. It looks more like:

**Options:**
    *string*  **$option1** This is option 1.
    *int*  **$thisIsTheSecondOption** This is option 2.

Which makes it more difficult to read.

:-\

Comment: Could you post your ALIASES to achieve this result? I'm struggling with the same problem. It's rather odd that doxygen won't allow this kind of rendering in an elegant way.

Comment: @Bruno: Sorry, this post was from four years ago. I'm at a different job and don't use Doxygen anymore. I honestly don't remember pretty much anything about it. But I don't recall using any kind of aliases. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that this is not possible without modifying doxygen. I would just use \li and list the options insteand of using \param then.

http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdli

Comment: Modifying doxygen would entail downloading the source code, modifying it, and compiling it, right? Probably more work than I'm looking to do for this. Perhaps I will submit a feature request. Using `\li`, can I make a header for the section of `\li` elements to let the user know that these are **Options**?