# Doxygen - Can you add your own header in method description?

Tags: c++, doxygen

Hello and thank you for reading.

I want to ask whether it is possible to add your own header in description of a method. I can not find any answer anywhere. 
Lets say:

```
     /**
     * @brief Adds a Character to a container. That monster will be updated and drawn. The monster is not added if monster with samee ID exists
     * @param m Character to add
     * @return false if the character was not added.
     */
    bool AddZombie(Zombie * m);
```

Now this will in doxygen create a field with bold headers saying "**Parameters**" and "**Returns**". 
What I want, however, is to add a paragraph for a **complexity**. The following code does not do what I want, however

```
     /**
     * @brief Adds a Character to a container. That monster will be updated and drawn. The monster is not added if monster with samee ID exists
     * @param m Character to add
     * @return false if the character was not added.
     * @complexity The complexity is O(n)
     */
    bool AddZombie(Zombie * m);
```

Now is there any way to do this? 
When I am asking here, please allow me to ask one small little question: 
Would it be possible to make a list of all complexities of methods, maybe sorted? Meaning not by coding html, by only using doxygen.

This might seem like a stupid question to people who know alot about doxygen, but, allthough I red documentation and the website, I still sometimes learn something new and hidden I did not know.
Thank you all for any response.

Have a nice day, and thank you for your time

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Custom Tags with Doxygen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/537043/custom-tags-with-doxygen)

Comment: See also: [Doxygen Manual Custom Commands](https://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/custcmd.html).

Comment: There's a lot more information when using the search keywords "doxygen custom tags".