# Requirement tracking using Doxygen

Tags: doxygen

I am trying to link requirement using doxygen,
I have created following tags:

```
srs{1}=\xrefitem srs "Software Requirement" "Software Requirement" \1
req{1}=\ref REQ_\1 "REQ-\1"

/**
@page Requirements

@anchor REQ_1
<a href="https://xyz">REQ_1</a>

@anchor REQ_2
<a href="https://xyz">REQ_2</a>
*/
```

in code I am adding following header to function:
    /**
     * @srs{@req{1}}
     * @brief
     * @param
     */

I am getting Software Requirement tag in Doxygen main page, also able to locate the function which implement the particular requirement. Only issue is whenever i am trying to open link e.g. REQ_1 which is generated by doxygen, which should direct me to my requirement link, instead of this it redirecting me to page(anchoring page) which shows all text such as REQ_1, REQ_2, from there I can jump to requirement link.

I am aware that the behavior is because of the way in which I did implementation.
Problem is I don't know another way :(
can any one suggest how can i avoid in between interface(anchoring page)? How I can jump directly to hyperlink from requirement tag?

Many thanks In advance - Abhi

Comment: I'm not sure if I got it correct but did you try something like:   "srs_new{1}=<b>Software Requirement:</b> <a href=\"https://xyz\">REQ_\1</a>" and in the code \srs_new{1}

Comment: The following discussion could be of interest to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/537043/custom-tags-with-doxygen