Doxygen: show refs to file
I want to show references to a file in doxygen documentation.
SETUP
I have three files in a directory: main.c, req.yml and dox.cfg
main.c content:
#include <stdio.h>

/**
 * @brief This function purpose is described in @ref req.yml
 */
void foo(int i)
{
    printf("foo: %d", i);
}

/**
 * @brief This function purpose is also described in @ref req.yml
 */
void bar(int i)
{
    printf("bar: %d", i);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    foo(1);
    bar(2);
    return 0;
}

req.yml:
## 
# @file
#
# This is a requirement file
#
# @showrefs
#
name: req1
text: This requirement purpose

dox.cfg:
PROJECT_NAME = "test
FILE_PATTERNS          = *.h \
                         *.yml \
                         *.c

EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
GENERATE_LATEX         = NO
GENERATE_XML           = NO
EXTENSION_MAPPING = yml=Python # interpret yml->python to make hashtag work
REFERENCES_LINK_SOURCE = YES
REFERENCED_BY_RELATION = YES

EFFECT
Both foo() and bar() have sections Referenced by main.c, but the requirement documentation file does not have such section.
GOAL
I would like to list (preferably in Referenced by section) that foo() and bar() reference that file, or any other way to visibly connect them without any proxy (pregenerated) file which would store that information.
I am using Doxygen 1.9.1
Yet, nothing works, the documentation page related to the yaml file does not show which elements reference it. Please help.

Which version of doxygen are you using?

I am running Doxygen 1.9.1

doxygen 1.9.1 is a bit older (January 8, 2021), the current doxygen version is 1.10.0. What happens when you use the current version?

Hey, I have updated the main description with proper test case, ready to run with doxygen dox.cfg

I think the problem here is the interpretation of the \showrefs command, thde documenattion states "When this command is put in a comment block of a function or method, then doxygen will generate an overview for
that function or method of the functions and methods that call it." but we don't see any function in req.yml., so nothing is  shown. I think you need something in the order of xrefitem and "requitement tracking" like in e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40955544/requirement-tracking-using-doxygen and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/537043/custom-tags-with-doxygen

Thanks for clarification and links!
