# Documenting error code implementation in doxygen

Tags: doxygen, doxygen-wizard

I am trying to generate documentation for some 'Error Codes' implemented in the code.
To start my work, I used the reference from:
[Custom tags with Doxygen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/537043/custom-tags-with-doxygen)
Using the `\xrefitem` and `ALIASES` option, I did the following.

```
ALIASES = "error{1}=\ref ErrorCode-\1 \"ErrorCode-\1\" " \
          "implement{1}=\xrefitem implement \"Implements ErrorCode\" \"ErrorCode Implementation\" \1" \
```

In the code I write the comment in FUNC1, for example:

```
@implement{@error{001}} Error Code 001
```

Using the above, I can generate a page where it shows the function name and which error codes are implemented in it.

Now, what I have is multiple sources of same Error Code in my project. So, in the documentation I would also like to have a page, where I can see the Error Code and where it is implemented (with links to the function).

What I have on page "ErrorCode Implementation":

```
FUNC1 
    Implements ErrorCode-001, ErrorCode-003

FUNC2 
    Implements ErrorCode-002
```

What I want on page "ErrorCode Tracing":

```
ErrorCode-001 
    Implemented in FUNC1, FUNC3

ErrorCode-002
    Implemented in FUNC2
```

How can this be done in Doxygen?

Comment: Which version of doxygen? What did you try so far, please add an example to your question.

Comment: I am using 1.8.13. I have modified the question a little. Hope it explains better.

Comment: Version 1.8.13 is from December 2016, what happens with the current version (1.8.19 or even better the current master from github)?

Comment: I think this is currently not possible.

Comment: I couldnt understand you. Do you think the newer versions will help in generating the desired page?

Comment: No I don't think so.

Comment: It seemed like something achievable. Curious to know why you say that?

Comment: Probably something achievable, but I don't know a direct way.

Comment: I can see links to the function on the page "Error Implementation", which of course are present because of the tags in the comment. Could there be a similar way to do it on page "Error Tracing"?